# Moving bitmap with SurfaceView is slow

Tags: android, performance, surfaceview

I am developing a game for android. Between stages, i want to show a part of a map with a route, and move it from a city to city (stage to stage).

First i want to do it on my phone, this a Samsung Galaxy Y, 240x320 Qvga ldpi.

So i have the map file in jpg format. This picture is 2463x602, this is a world map.
I did it, everything is done except one thing. This "animation" is slow for me.

When i start with this, i thought, it will be so fast, and i will handle the speed with a Thread.sleep(); but the matter is, it is not fast.

How can i make it more faster this?
Here is my code:

```
package hu.mycompany.myproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MapActivity extends Activity {

    DrawView drawView;
    SoundPool soundPool;
    int soundId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.airplane, 1);
        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(drawView);
    }

    public void playSound() {
        soundPool.play(soundId, 1f, 1f, 1, 0, 1f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        playSound();
        drawView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        drawView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class DrawView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        Bitmap gameMap = null;
        Thread gameLoop = null;
        SurfaceHolder surface;
        Rect rect;
        volatile boolean running;
        volatile boolean moved;

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            moved = false;
            surface = getHolder();
            gameMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.map);

        }

        public void resume() {
            running = true;
            gameLoop = new Thread(this);
            gameLoop.start();
        }

        public void pause() {
            running = false;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    gameLoop.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rect canvasSize = new Rect(0, 0, 240, 320);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            while (running) {
                if (!surface.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!moved) {
                    int i;
                    for (i = 80; i <= 830; i++) {
                        Canvas canvas = surface.lockCanvas();
                        rect = new Rect(i, 250, (i + 240), 570);
                        canvas.drawBitmap(gameMap, rect, canvasSize, paint);
                        surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                    }
                    moved = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention, the file size of the picture is 145KB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-try to reduce picture size by exporting it save for web in photoshop and select png as extension type
2- You should create two class one for handling thread and other for rendering and game logic. The thread will manage it by locking canvas when system is rendering. Take a look at this link
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-surfaceview.html

Comment: I tried to reduce the size of my picture. PNG will be bigger, this is why i choose the jpg with low quality. Now i cut the picture to the half, so now it's 82,2KB and 1210x602.

it's faster a littlebit more, but not significally.

And anyway, if you see my code, i do exactly what you say. There is the class for rendering, named DrawView.

(If the blog what you recommend me is yours, check the downloadable file, Avira tells me it contains virus).

Comment: no it's not mine, i just found it on search results, btw the code should work out, why you need to download sourcce file ?

edit: i found another, try this one, http://obviam.net/index.php/a-very-basic-the-game-loop-for-android/

Comment: of course i tried to copy/paste that project, it tells me at line 46:
Suspicious method call; should probably call "draw" rather than "onDraw"

I thought that is your blog, this is why i tell you. I check your second link too.

Comment: ok, now i imported this project, and extends the MainThread.java run() function with my for loop. The result is the same.

Comment: hımm, maybe it is the maximum performance you get? :) try to do some analysis with ddms, tracer etc. and try to find something that you think uses memory/cpu too much, if you got what you suspect then it'S ok otherwise i guess that's what you get max :)